# How to get {{>partials} working with Consolidate.js & Mustache?

Tags: node.js, express, templating, mustache

I cannot get mustache reading partials added like so {{>my_partial}} when using it with consolidate.js. I start my express application with something like:

file index.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    cons    = require('consolidate'); 

app.configure(function(){

  app.set( 'models',       BACKEND + '/models' );       // Set the models directory
  app.set( 'views',        BACKEND + '/views' );        // Set the views directory
  app.set( 'controllers',  BACKEND + '/controllers' );  // Set the controllers dir


  app.set( 'view engine',  'html' );                // Set Mustache as the templating engine
  app.engine( 'html', cons.mustache );
  app.engine( 'mustache', cons.mustache );

  app.use( app.router );  // Set the router
  app.use( '/public', express.static( BASEPATH + '/frontend/public' ) );  // set frontend/public to /public for users
  app.use( '/js', express.static( BASEPATH + '/frontend/js' ) );
  app.use( '/out', express.static( BASEPATH + '/out' ) ); // documentation path

  // Set client side libraries here (Make them available to the public based on settings.json)
  for(setting in SETTINGS.public) {
    app.use( SETTINGS.public[setting],  express.static(BASEPATH + SETTINGS.public[setting]) );
  }

});
```

Then, somewhere in the controller, I use the render like so:

```
function Blog(app, request, response){

  var fs      =  require('fs'), 
      Blog    =  require( app.get('models') + '/blog' ),
      model   =  new Blog(),
      scripts =  fs.readFileSync( VIEWS + '/m_scripts.mustache').toString()     ;

  model.List(function(data){

    response.render('layout', 
      {
        title     :  'My Blog',
        body      :  'Hello Mustache World',
        list      :  data.rows,
        cache     :  false,
        partials  : {
          m_scripts : partialStr
        }
      }
    );

  });

};


exports.list = Blog;
```

The m_scripts.mustache has:

```
<script data-src="ergierjgoejoij"></script>
```

The layout template renders just fine, and the params pass through just fine too, the partial m_scripts gets passed with the text passed by readFileSync().toString() just fine BUT the HTML stuff gets encoded and rendered useless.

My question is, is there a way I can just put in the layout.mustache {{>m_scripts}} and mustache understands to load the m_scripts.mustache automatically without the need to pass it to the render(). If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, at this moment, consolidate.js does not support partials. There is a pull request to fix this but it hasn't been merged: https://github.com/simov/consolidate.js

I ended up using that fork instead by:

1) npm uninstall consolidate

2) npm install simov/consolidate.js

npm install simov/consolidate.js will install that forked version. Then I can do the following:

```
/**
 * @module Blog Controller
 */ 
function Blog(app, request, response){

  var Blog    =  require( app.get('models') + '/blog' ),
      model   =  new Blog();

  model.List(function(data){

    response.render('layout', 
      {
        title     :  'My Blog',
        body      :  'Hello Mustache World',
        list      :  data.rows,
        cache     :  false
        ,partials  : {
          m_scripts : './backend/views/m_scripts.html'
        }
      }
    );

  });

};


exports.list = Blog;
```

It's a lot simpler than I thought. You pass the path to your partial instead and then you can use {{>m_scripts}} on the layout.html

Still, not sure if there is a way to make it, by default, look for {{>m_scripts}} on the views folder or something. That would be neat.

Comment: How can we pass dynamic data in partial files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hogan](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/) instead of Mustache. Hogan will render templates with partials which you set in `app.set('partials', partialsPathMap)` as a path map.

You can use code in this [gist:5149597](https://gist.github.com/mytharcher/5149597) in your project. Then you do not need any more partials config when rendering templates.

---

Edited 2014-06-23:

For simpler, I wrote a npm to handle this. Just `npm install mustlayout`, the repository and document is here: https://github.com/mytharcher/mustlayout

Comment: Thanks, will give Hogan a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this topic because i wanted to know how Consolidate works with partials and found out that Consolidate now is able to use partials just fine.

1. Create a views folder and create a file called index.hbs
2. Add the line {{>menuPartial}} somewhere in the HTML
3. Create a sub fodler of views called partials
4. Create a file called menu.hbs

Then you can use this Node script to make the partial work:

```
const express = require('express');
const engines = require('consolidate');


const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', engines.handlebars);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.render('index', { partials : { menuPartial : './partials/menu'} });
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```